# Is there a way to have Dir output file Height?

Tags: windows-explorer, cmd.exe

In File Explorer I can detail the height of images: 
[image]

I can use Copyfilenames or even dir > files.csv to print the file list.

Is there a way I can get it to print the Height in pixels? Or is there another way I can grab the heights easily en masse? I tried the powershell script that drew the image, but it is extremely resource intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out a way. If you Google this you cannot find the solution anywhere. Hopefully one day it helps someone else.

Install ImageMagick

use CMD "magick identify -format "%f %w %h" *.tif"

Comment: Nick, it is encouraged for you to accept your own answer (you may have  to wait until you can), as that will help others who read this question in future. Glad you found your solution :-)

Comment: Thank you did so. The Powershell scripts eat a ton of resources. ImageMagick did it almost instantly with no lag or harm on the cpu.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a solution that doesn't require installing additional software, here is an answer that includes a Powershell script that retrieves the dimensions without drawing each image.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420055/enumerate-file-properties-in-powershell

(Caution: the width, height, and dimensions attributes are 27, 28, and 26 in the example code, but they are 177, 179, and 31 on my system. Use the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420055/enumerate-file-properties-in-powershell to find out what they are for you.)